# Making a random number matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to make a 5 x 10 matrix of 0s, 1s, and 5s with equal numbers of 0s, 1s, and 5s in the matrix (or 16, 17, 17 since 16+17+17 = 50). This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to make the number of 0s = number of 1s = number of 5s.

```
r <- 10
c <- 5
m0 <- matrix(0, r, c)
a <- matrix(0, 1, 16)
b <- matrix(1, 1, 17)
c  <- matrix(5, 1, 17)
apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(a,b,c),1, replace = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the `sample` function a vector, then it will shuffle those numbers randomly. Therefore, all you need to do is to shuffle the numbers and store them in a matrix:

```
set.seed(144)
matrix(sample(rep(c(0, 1, 5), c(16, 17, 17))), 5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    1    1    5    0    5    0    5    1     1
# [2,]    5    0    0    1    0    5    5    5    5     1
# [3,]    5    1    1    1    1    1    5    0    0     5
# [4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0     1
# [5,]    0    5    5    0    1    5    5    5    5     0
```